# Регистрация пользователей для телеграм бота

Tags: c#

Пишу телеграм бота. Пытаюсь внести username и chatId в таблицу, но при запуске программы компилятор начинает ругаться на вот эту строчку "regcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();".

```
public static void Registration(string chatId, string username)
    {
        try
        {
            DB = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=DB.db;"); 
            DB.Open(); 
            SQLiteCommand regcmd = DB.CreateCommand();
            regcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RegUsers VALUES(@chatId, @username)";
            regcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chatId", chatId); 
            regcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            regcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DB.Close();  
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Саму БД закинул в папку с решением. Делал по видеоуроку, там все работало, а у меня почему-то нет.
UPD: Проблема фактически в том, что данные в таблицу не вносятся.
Ниже выполнение самого метода, в нем ошибок вроде нет.

```
if (message.Text == "/reg")
     {
  Registration(message.Chat.Id.ToString(), message.Chat.Username.ToString());
await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Пользователь зарегистрирован");
}
```

Comment: Какой бд пользуетесь?

Comment: SQLite Studio (3.2.1)

Comment: Мой вам совет, раз хотите сохранять данные в простой файлик, то посмотрите в сторону [LiteDB](https://www.litedb.org/), она и проще и легче и удобней.

Comment: `но при запуске программы компилятор начинает ругаться` Так компилятор ругается или ошибка во время выполнения? И да, прикладывайте ошибку в текстовом виде, мы не телепаты чтобы гадать что за у вас ошибка.